# Can't add a rightBarButtonItem to a NavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to build an app (for practice) that uses CoreData and different view controllers.
I'm currently blocked, because I can't manage to add a `rightBarButtonItem` to a navigationBar.
Here is the code I'm using (in the `AppDelegate`, application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).

```
PersoneTableViewController *ptvc = [[PersoneTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
ptvc.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
ptvc.title = @"Persone";

UINavigationController *navCon = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[navCon pushViewController:ptvc animated:NO];

UIBarButtonItem *barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                  target:self
                                  action:@selector(addPressed)];
navCon.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
[barButtonItem release];

self.window.rootViewController = navCon;

[navCon release];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

But the rightBarButtonItem is not showed if I run the app in the simulator.

Comment: Solved, I just needed to add the barButtonItem to the pushed ViewController, not the navigationController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `UInavigationController` will use the `navigationItem` from it's topmost view controller *(and second to topmost for the back button)*. Not it's own `navigationItem` as in your example.